# What's the point of SPF if an attacker spoofs the "From" address?

Tags: email, mail-server, spf, spoofing, email-spam

Based on my current understanding, SPF is only concerned about validating that the sending email server IP is listed in the SPF records for the domain of the "envelope from" (Return-Path/MAIL FROM). Since spoofing is done usually on the "From" address shown to the receiver, the "envelope from" address will be from the domain of the malicious actor, and a DNS lookup for the SPF record will include the IP address of the server used to send the spoofed email, and SPF will pass. Am I wrong and if not, what is the point of SPF on its own? Why would a malicious actor even want to spoof the "envelope from"?

Why wasn't SPF designed to use the "From" address instead? Wouldn't that have ensured that who pretends to be john@gmail.com (as address visible to the end receiver) is actually john@gmail.com? Then the receiver would see john@gmail.com and they would know that it is john, because the IP of the sending server is listed in as an IP of gmail.com, so then it must come from gmail.com and can't have been spoofed.

Wouldn't that have made DKIM less necessary? Was this not accepted because of relays, forwarding, encryption or other things that might have interfered on the way of the email to its final destination?

Comment: This assumes the attacker can send from an SPF-listed IP, which is really only the case on shared infrastructure (e.g. Gmail) and not self-owned IPs. It's also why DKIM exists as DKIM operates on the From: level.

Comment: You may want to use DMARC in addition to SPF (and DKIM). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC#Alignment

Comment: Many clients will show a "via" hint if the domain of the envelope sender and "From:" address differ, an acknowledgement of the fact that spoofing can happen.

Comment: @tadman I meant that the attacker could own the domain and IP. As an example, let's suppose the attacker has the domain badwebsite.com and has a mail server running at that domain. They set up an SPF record for the domain that includes the IP of that mail server and send an email to john@gmail.com from the address ("From:") jane@gmail.com. Wouldn't SPF succeed because badwebsite.com matches its own IP, therefore no need to use a shared service/email provider like Gmail?

Comment: If they control the domain then they can set up SPF, DKIM, and whatever else to at least *appear* legitimate, however this is where domain and IP reputation play in, as if they are malicious they'll quickly degrade that reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed SPF does not validate the From address within the message, and that's a design limitation of SPF, which only operates at the SMTP level, and has nothing to say about message content. However, that's not a problem because we have DMARC, which validates DKIM and SPF results *and* the From address within the message.

Comment: Isn't it only DKIM that considers the From header during its signing process on its own?

Comment: DKIM can certainly sign the from header, but it doesn’t apply any other kind of validation to it; it just confirms that it has not been changed since the message was sent. This is why you need to implement all 3 systems, as they are complementary and reinforce each other.